# squid url_rewrite with cookie

Tags: cookies, squid, urlrewriter

I have a squid 3.0 deployed which has a url_rewriter program which rewrites certain HTTP requests.
I now need to modify this prpogram to rewrite along with the cookie setting code.

As much as I have seen the [url_rewrite_program documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_program/), it appears that I may not be able to set a cookie along with the 302 response.

Is this correct? 
Can i set a cookie in the redirect response or would this require modifying the squid code.

Appreciate any help in this regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailing list confirmed that url_rewriter and squid protocol as of today does not support setting the cookie .

I have modified the squid code myself to do this
Now you could set the cookie by returning the following line from your url_rewriter program

`302:<URL>#<SET_COOKIE>`

for example ,

`302:http://my.example.net#cookie_name=cookie_value;path=1;expiration=+300`

One caveat (more for my own documentation),
you cannot place a space in the cookie string as the squid reading function rejects anything after  a whitespace.

Anybody interested in the patch ,let me know